# Moved XAMPP folder to new computer, now getting "(XAMPPErrorDomain error 1.)" when trying to start up MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I recently had to reinstall Lion from scratch on my MacBook. I saved my XAMPP folder and moved it into the applications folder in my new install. I can start up Apache, but not MySQL. I get this error: "`The operation couldn’t be completed. (XAMPPErrorDomain error 1.)`".

I tried setting permissions on the var/mysql to 775 and 777, neither worked.

I tried running "`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`" in terminal and I get this: "

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

" When I checked the error file it generated, I see this:

"

```
110820 14:41:20 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
110820 14:41:20 [Warning] The syntax '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use --skip-external-locking instead.
110820 14:41:20 [Warning] option 'thread_stack': unsigned value 65536 adjusted to 131072
110820 14:41:20 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
110820 14:41:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110820 14:41:20  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
110820 14:41:20 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/hex-sha6-ev11435.concordia.ca.pid ended
```

"

Any ideas? The only thing that changed from my old OS install to my new one is the name of the computer changed from Scott's Macbook to Scott's Mac**B**ook. It worked fine on 10.7 before I had to erase the drive and reinstall everything.

Answer (score 13):

Permissions problem,
simply do

`chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var`

And you're good to go.

Comment: This did not solve for me. The command prompt includes that mysql started but it does not start

Comment: Using unix command 'sudo' and log in as admin works. Thanks!! --- sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var