# Xampp Won't Startup MySQL server on Mac OSX?

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion, xampp

I'm on a Mac OSX Mountain Lion. Xampp won't let me start MySQL server.

I have set the permissions to Read/Write for everyone and every file in the XAMPP folder.

[image]

The error message shows "The operation couldn't be completed. (XAMPPErrorDomain error 1.)"

Any ideas on how to stop other MySQL processes. I have tried following this Lynda.com Tutorial on fixing port conflicts. I tried typing in this command "sudo lsof -i -P | grep 3306" in Terminal.

However it didn't work, I wanted to test to see if MySQL is running however nothing returned. How can I check to see if any other versions are running, then stop any other MySQL servers/ Uninstall the other possible version?

Here is the error Log Screenshot? Is that what you were looking for?
[image]

[image]

***Here is the error Log:***

```
[Tue Dec 11 10:46:28 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Dec 11 10:46:29 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 11 10:46:29 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 11 10:46:29 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 11 11:00:02 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 11 11:00:33 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Dec 11 11:00:34 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 11 11:00:34 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 11 11:00:34 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 11 14:14:23 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 11 14:17:31 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Dec 11 14:17:32 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 11 14:17:32 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 11 14:17:32 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
sendmail: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file or directory
sendmail: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file or directory
[Tue Dec 11 16:07:41 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jessleigh/wp-admin/function.unlink, referer: http://localhost/jessleigh/wp-admin/admin.php?page=functions.php
[Tue Dec 11 16:41:51 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 11 17:08:44 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Dec 11 17:08:45 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 11 17:08:45 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 11 17:08:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 11 17:38:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/jessleigh
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/jessleigh
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:39 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:44 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:45 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:45 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:46 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/jessleigh
[Tue Dec 11 17:57:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/jessleigh
[Tue Dec 11 17:58:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/jessleigh
[Tue Dec 11 19:57:16 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jessleigh/sample-page, referer: http://localhost/jessleigh/
[Tue Dec 11 20:07:09 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jessleigh/sample-page, referer: http://localhost/jessleigh/
[Tue Dec 11 20:31:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jessleigh/home, referer: http://localhost/jessleigh/wp-admin/post.php?post=41&action=edit&message=6
[Fri Dec 14 13:15:33 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[Fri Dec 14 18:20:53 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Dec 14 18:20:54 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Dec 14 18:20:54 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Dec 14 18:20:54 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 14 18:24:24 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 18 12:00:06 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Dec 18 12:00:07 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 18 12:00:07 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 18 12:00:07 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
:
```

Comment: tail -2 /opt/lampp/logs/error_log

Comment: @JonathandeM. Hey, I'm using Xampp not Lampp? How would I use that command anyway?

Comment: tail -2 /opt/xampp/logs/error_log, use the autocompletion, I'm not sure about the path

Comment: error_log is the apache error log. Mysql error log should be <machine-name>.err don't know the path in xampp. I use AMPPS.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can check if any instance of mysql is running by executing in the terminal

```
sudo ps aux | grep mysql
```

this will list any processes that have mysql in their name.

```
_mysql          18943   0,0  0,5  2514608  20340 s008  S+    5:46am   0:00.07   /opt/local/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/opt/local --datadir=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5 --  user=_mysql --log-error=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/Max-NB.local.err --pid-  file=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/Max-NB.local.pid
root            18900   0,0  0,1  2439964   2592 s008  S+    5:46am   0:00.15 /bin/sh   /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5
root            18899   0,0  0,1  2439396   2616 s008  S+    5:46am   0:00.02 sudo   mysqld_safe5
```

you may then terminate the process by executing

```
sudo killall mysqld_safe5
```

you should replace "mysqld_safe5" by the name of your mysql process. It is most likely "mysqld".

After that you could try to restart your server and check if it works.

Comment: Why `sudo ps aux` instead of just `ps aux`?

Comment: I see from the screenshot you are trying to view your error.log by just pasting the name of the logfile into terminal. By doing this bash  assumes you are running a script on that path. try running "less /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log" instead

Comment: @WaleedKhan it should work without sudo as well, I was however not shure if it would display root processes when running as normal user.

Comment: @MaxI have uploaded a screenshot I'm unsure on how to kill that process?

Comment: Hi Josh, the process you are seeing is your grep command (It is running by the time you are executing ps). It does not look as if any instance of mysql is being run. Please post the content of the log files, everything else would come down to guessing whats wrong.

Comment: error_log is the apache error log. Mysql error log should be <machine-name>.err don't know the path in xampp. I use AMPPS.

Comment: The CORRECT ANSWER was to reinstall Xampp and start again, but this was the closest. :)

Answer (score 12):

```
chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var
```

fixed the problem for me. Refer - [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324882/240255)

However do **not** do this in production servers, you may need to change the owner or group (`chown` or `chgrp` to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First read the error file located at **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log**, normally this error occurs if something is running on port 3306 already.

Comment: I opened that file and took a screenshot of it in Terminal added it above how do I view the error_log?

Comment: Please check if you have put your XAMPP folder on Root folder for e.g.-/Applications, if you have put your xampp folder other than root (nested to some level like (/Applications/abc/xampp) than sometimes it creats problem.

Comment: Yep it's defitely in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but managed to solve it by replacing my.cnf with the original file.
It had the following line coming removing which solved the problem.

```
listen 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to configure your MySql Database and change you port from 3306 to 3307 , this work for me . Sometimes this port is busy and does not work for your pc.

Comment: You realize the original question was posted in 2012, right?

Answer (score 0):

looks into the error log and you may find:

[ERROR] Bad magic header in tc log
[ERROR] Can't init tc log

delete /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/tc.log and restart the mysql

Answer (score -3):

You can use MAMP PRO on your Mac book.But one problem is there, if you don't register or active it will work only 14days.

I share some screenshots here...

1.After you installed it, open and select the phpMyAdmin[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZDXC.png)

2.next you go to Database[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxY2n.png)

3.then you can create database and you can add columns there[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS4gW.png)

Comment: The question are from 8 years ago. And the answer just doesn't answer the question (requesting to change software are not a solution of a problem with some software).