# Tried every thing still getting ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, sockets

Every time I run XAMPP and try to run `$mysql -u root -p`, its throwing me an error which is:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I am using XAMPP version 1.7.3 in Mac OS-10.9. Starting Apache and MySQL is not a problem and I have confirmed Apache has started by going to activity monitor.

Few things I tried:

1. checked if MySQL is running by typing this command in terminal: `mysqladmin -u root -p status`. Result was:

   > mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
   > error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
   > Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
2. I checked and found mysql.sock file in `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

Things that could have triggered this error but cant say what is wrong:

1. I recently upgraded my OS to Mavericks from Mountain Lion.
2. I had also installed separate MySQL to work with Ruby on Rails. I have made sure that version is off.

Without fixing this problem I am not able to do any development locally and connecting MySQL in PHP script seems impossible. So any help will be appreciated.

Here is error_log file from `/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/logs/error_log`:

```
[Sat Nov 02 09:56:31 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 02 09:56:39 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Nov 02 09:56:40 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Nov 02 09:56:40 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Nov 02 09:56:40 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 02 12:55:47 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 02 13:40:16 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Nov 02 13:40:18 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Nov 02 13:40:18 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Nov 02 13:40:18 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 02 15:12:39 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 02 20:54:41 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Nov 02 20:54:43 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Nov 02 20:54:43 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Nov 02 20:54:44 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 02 21:10:53 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 02 21:10:57 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Nov 02 21:10:58 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Nov 02 21:10:58 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Nov 02 21:10:58 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 02 21:31:39 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 02 21:31:44 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Nov 02 21:31:47 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Nov 02 21:31:47 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Nov 02 21:31:47 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 02 21:45:07 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 03 08:50:06 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Nov 03 08:50:09 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Nov 03 08:50:09 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Nov 03 08:50:10 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Did you increase the max_connection size in the my.cnf ?

Answer (score 15):

Finally manage to solve it. 
First I was looking on wrong directory, I should have looked into `/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/`.

List of things I did:

1. there was not tmp folder under /applications/xampp/xamppfiles, so I created it (mkdir tmp).
2. I searched for mysql.sock file and found it under `/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

As mysql server connection was not working via socket `/tmp/mysql.sock`, I used following command to point my `/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock` to `/tmp/mysql.sock` file.

So this command did the trick:

```
ln -s /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

3. now I restart xampp services and run: `mysql -u root -p` , I can get into mysql console. And I also tried connecting mysql from php script and its running ok.

After pulling hair for a day and half I finally managed to get it working hope people will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you get a list of running programs on a mac but you should try and verify that mysqld is actually running.   (on linux "top -bn1 | grep mysql" would normally show a line of info if it is running, or nothing if it is not.)

You could also try stopping mysqld and see if /tmp/mysql.sock vanishes.  If it doesn't then try deleting it and restarting mysql to see if it appears again. (it should)

Do you have any log files that might show what is going on?

Comment: I can not find mysql.sock file under tmp folder.      RoshanComputer:tmp Roshan$ pwd
/tmp
RoshanComputer:tmp Roshan$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  7 root        wheel  238 Nov  3 08:53 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root        wheel  204 Oct 28 21:14 ..
drwx------  3 Roshan      wheel  102 Nov  2 18:57 launch-6U3stf
drwx------  3 Roshan      wheel  102 Nov  2 18:57 launch-JtLO7T
drwx------  3 Roshan      wheel  102 Nov  2 18:57 launchd-160.pc1D6V
drwx------  3 _spotlight  wheel  102 Nov  2 18:58 launchd-320.Jgh4Fa
drwx------  3 root        wheel  102 Nov  2 21:45 launchd-3875.fJ7OWJ

Comment: That suggests to me that mysql is not actually running.  See if you can find a log file of some kind.  Maybe someone else who is familiar with where things live on a MAC can chime in and point you to them.  The log will probably show an error of some kind.

Comment: sorry i was looing in wrong path that was /tmp instead of /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/tmp. Actually mysql.sock file was there and i tried to switch off xampp services and file did not vanish. so i deleted manually. After i restarted xampp mysql.sock file has not been created. Trying to find log file for mysql in mac but no luck.

Comment: And also to confirm mysql is running i checked activity monitor and mysqld is showing it that window and as i switch off it goes and when i switch xampp On it reappears. I guess that means mysql is working. But dont know what the problem is?

Comment: Maybe the link below will help a little. (It has a screenshot suggesting where to find the logs)   I need to get to bed now so won't be able to reply any more tonight.  Good luck.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097399/xampp-wont-startup-mysql-server-on-mac-osx

Comment: The problem could be that mysql.sock is being created somewhere else and when you are trying to connect to it, your mysql client is looking in the wrong place.   Use a find utility to search your computer for mysql.sock and see where it is (if it exists!) and then compare its location with the path in the error message to confirm if they do or don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your mysql server is not started. Use the following commands:

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP mac has the default settings to store mysql.sock another location.
Just change it :)

```
$ vim /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf

[client]
#password   = your_password
port        =3306
#socket     =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
socket      =/tmp/mysql.sock         <---------

...

[mysqld]
user=mysql
port=3306
#socket     =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
socket      =/tmp/mysql.sock        <---------
```

Restart mysql, then works.